# Javascript img onclick always click all imgs, can't catch correct img which clicked

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I use an array to store my all `imgs` by `getElementsByClassName`.

I need to know which `img` is clicked or `mouseover`/`mouseout`, so I use a loop to check which `img` is clicked.

But, I don't get which one is clicked. It always gets all of the `imgs`, not which one I clicked.

How can I fixed it? Thank you!

Here is my HTML:

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-6 userPic_area">
        <img class="userPicImgs" src="./view/images/head/head_1.png" alt="" width="100%">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-6 userPic_area">
        <img class="userPicImgs" src="./view/images/head/head_2.png" alt="" width="100%">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-6 userPic_area">
        <img class="userPicImgs" src="./view/images/head/head_3.png" alt="" width="100%">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-6 userPic_area">
        <img class="userPicImgs" src="./view/images/head/head_4.png" alt="" width="100%">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-6 userPic_area">
        <img class="userPicImgs" src="./view/images/head/head_5.png" alt="" width="100%">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-6 userPic_area">
        <img class="userPicImgs" src="./view/images/head/head_6.png" alt="" width="100%">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-6 userPic_area">
        <img class="userPicImgs" src="./view/images/head/head_7.png" alt="" width="100%">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-6 userPic_area">
         <img class="userPicImgs" src="./view/images/head/head_8.png" alt="" width="100%">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-6 userPic_area">
         <img class="userPicImgs" src="./view/images/head/head_9.png" alt="" width="100%">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-6 userPic_area">
         <img class="userPicImgs" src="./view/images/head/head_10.png" alt="" width="100%">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-6 userPic_area">
         <img class="userPicImgs" src="./view/images/head/head_11.png" alt="" width="100%">
      </div>
  </div>
```

Here is my JS:

```
function clickUserPicImgs(){

    var UserPicArea = document.getElementsByClassName('userPic_area');
    var UserPicImgs = document.getElementsByClassName('userPicImgs');

    //console.log(UserPicImgs);

    var num;

    function isClicked(num){
        console.log(num);   
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < UserPicImgs.length; i++){

        UserPicImgs[i].onclick = isClicked(i);
    }
}

clickUserPicImgs();
```

Comment: When do you use `UserPicArea` in your javascript?

Comment: `var num` is also outside of your `isClicked` function, and thus is neither used nor set. I think `var num` just needs to be deleted since your function will work anyway with `i` later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This :

```js
function clickUserPicImgs(num){
  var UserPicArea = document.getElementsByClassName('userPic_area');
  var UserPicImgs = document.getElementsByClassName('userPicImgs');
  for(var i = 0; i < UserPicImgs.length; i++){
    if (num === UserPicImgs[i] ) 
      console.log(i)
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <img class="userPicImgs" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRDAYrQr9qgT2W00EV_CoCahFki3Vw4lSMNt81k9FCSTXoKT8TY2w" alt="" width="20%" onclick="clickUserPicImgs(this)">
  <img class="userPicImgs" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQEnn9dYYZlciBKfaHCw17-dUgRPX3nq5_6-kV1ua-LIsId5g43uA" alt="" width="20%" onclick="clickUserPicImgs(this)">
  <img class="userPicImgs" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSeY54SaYkaOxxyXlu_ng21EMIBZvJjnZBNQAOsIh_0_6Tvu9et" alt="" width="20%" onclick="clickUserPicImgs(this)">
</div>
```